# Como setar o primeiro valor na combo?

Tags: angular, combobox, dropdown

Galera, preciso de um help:

Estou tentando setar o primeiro estado na combo, já coloquei o selected porém sem sucesso. Alguém sabe me informar o que pode estar errado, ou algo que me ajude a solucionar.

Meu código:

```
<div class="col s6">
     <label>Escolha seu estado</label>
     <select [(ngModel)]="municipio.estado" (change)="buscarCidadesPorEstado($event.target.value)" name="estado" class="browser-default">
     <option selected [value]="e.estado" *ngFor="let e of estados" >{{e.estado}}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Aguardo sugestões de solução. Obrigada!!

Comment: Do jeito que está seu código, todos os "options" estão com a tag "selected" - o que não é desejável, você pode retirar o "selected" e setar o valor inicial diretamente em "municipio.estado" (no typescript).

Comment: Qual é a versão do angular?

Comment: WallaceMaxters é 5 a versão que estou trabalhando

Answer (score 0):

1. vá no seu controller.
2. no método:

```
     ngOnInit() { 
         //Pode ser que tenha algo aqui.     
         municipio.estado = estados[0];
     }
```

OBS: Se for um request async que está preenchendo o array de estados, atribuir para a propriedade (municipio.estado) após esse array ser preenchido.

Answer (score 0):

Para trabalhar com `select` no Angular2 é preciso que você coloque a diretiva `compareWith` e caso necessite que possua uma opção inicial em branco adicione fora do `ngFor`. Nesse seu caso ficaria assim:

```
<div class="col s6">
     <label>Escolha seu estado</label>
     <select [(ngModel)]="municipio.estado" (change)="buscarCidadesPorEstado($event.target.value)" 
        [compareWith]="compareWith" name="estado" class="browser-default">
     <option selected [value]="">Selecione...</option>
     <option [value]="e.estado" *ngFor="let e of estados" >{{e.estado}}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

E no seu componente:

```
compareWith(a: any, b: any): boolean {
    return a && b ? a.id === b.id : a === b;
}
```

O `compareWith` vai selecionar a opção no combo automaticamente quando o `ngValue` alterar. A documentação está [neste link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cf0968f98e844043a0f6c2548201f3c0dfd329a7/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts#L72). Espero ter ajudado

Edit: Esqueci de avisar, utilize `[value]` para strings e `[ngValue]` para objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar o atributo value da tag select com o valor que você deseja que ele carregue selecionado:

```
<div class="col s6">
     <label>Escolha seu estado</label>
     <select [(ngModel)]="municipio.estado" value="municipioSelecionado" (change)="buscarCidadesPorEstado($event.target.value)" name="estado" class="browser-default">
     <option selected [value]="e.estado" *ngFor="let e of estados" >{{e.estado}}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

onde o municipioSelecionado é uma variável com o id do estado que deve carregar pré-selecionado.

[- Pergunta relacionada.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009331/select-default-option-value-from-typescript-angular-6)

[- Segue um exemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwdref?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)